# Displaying random characters instead of Unicode in mysql database.?

Tags: php, mysql, database, unicode

I need to save some sentences which are in Bengali unicode.Such as

```
 আমি ভাত খাই ( english: I eat rice)
```

For that purpose I created a database with collation 'utf8_unicode_ci' in MySql.
Now in a table whenever I insert a new sentence it shows some random characters.Such as for the above line phpmyadmin displays ,

```
 à¦†à¦®à¦¿ à¦­à¦¾à¦¤ à¦–à¦¾à¦‡
```

I tried to solve this in many ways,but nothing worked.I also added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in the head section.

But when I insert a unicode sentence such as ' আমি ভাত খাই ' directly from phpmyadmin>insert it works.

Please help.Thank You.

<< my code in smallest >>

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Thesis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="frame">
            <table  style="width:95%;margin:0 0 0 2%;  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);"><tr><td  align="center"><font color="#000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;Natural Language Processing - Sentence Store For N-Gram </font></td></tr></table> <br />
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table  style="width:100%; height:auto">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text"   class="outer" style="width:90%; font-size:20px;height:25px; font-weight:bold;" name="data" required autofocus onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)
                        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"  ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id = "btnSearch" value="Save" style="width:200px;height:40px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; color:#0099FF"/></td>
                    </tr>
               </table>    
            </form>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        include('db.php');
            $data = trim($_POST['data']);
            $qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO sentence_tab VALUES('','$data')");
            if($qry){
                echo "SUCCESS";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "FAILURE";
            }
    }       
?>
```

Comment: Change from `mysql_*` interface to `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe trying to set which character set you are using helps. As far as I know the setting you did in mysql with utf8_unicode_ci is just how to save it in database. Now you have to ensure you are delivering in the same charset.

I would try something like

```
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
```

right before the mysql_query()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your character set of database, table and the column is "utf8_general_ci".
2. after your mysql connection code put this code

`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db_con);` 
OR
`mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db_con);`

This should fix your issue.